# Finding other eigenvalue of matrix given one eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I have two questions:

1) Suppose $A$ is a diagonalizable $2 \times 2$ matrix and has determinant $1$. Suppose also that one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $2$. Find all the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$.

2) Give two examples of $2 \times 2$ matrices that have the same eigenvalues, one of which is diagonalizable, while the other is not.

We just started learning about eigenvalues etc, and I can't find anything in my text book that will help me.

Answer (score 2):

1) 
Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ the eigenvalues of $A$.

We know that $\lambda_1=2$.

We have that $\det A = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 $

By assumption, $\det A = 1$ so $1= 2\lambda_2$ and hence $\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Finally the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$, respectively $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$.

2)Consider  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$ and  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

1) Given an invertible matrix $A$ with $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue, $1\over\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Also det($A$) = det($A^{-1}$), and with the property that the product of the eigenvalues is the determinant of the matrix, we have:

$1/2 \cdot \lambda_2 = 1$

So the eigenvalues are $1/2, 2$.